# CopyFolder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have folders name in one column, I have to search that folders name in Source Folder, if it matched. I want to paste that folders to Destination Folder.
Is there any VBA Code for that

Only file copying VBA I found.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfolder-method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Folders Using the FileSystemObject Object

**Microsoft**

- [`FileSystemObject object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object)
- [`FolderExists method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folderexists-method)
- [`BuildPath method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/buildpath-method)
- [`CopyFolder method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfolder-method)

  - About the 1st and 2nd arguments, *source* and *destination*:

  > If *source* contains wildcard characters, or ***destination* ends with
  > a path separator (), it is assumed that *destination* is an existing
  > folder** in which to copy matching folders and subfolders.

  - About the 3rd argument *overwrite*:

  > Optional. Boolean value that indicates if existing folders are to be
  > overwritten. If **True**, files are overwritten; if **False**, they
  > are not. The default is **True**.

  > If a file contained in *source* already exists in *destination*, an
  > error     occurs if *overwrite* is **False**.

**The Code**

```
Sub CopyFolders()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Source"
    Const DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Destination"
    
    ' Check if the folders exist.
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "Source folder " & SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH _
             & "' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH) Then
        MsgBox "Destination folder " & DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH _
             & "' not found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the single-column range.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Write the values from the range to a 2D one-based one-column array.
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then ' one cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Write the values from the array to a dictionary
    ' removing errors, blanks and duplicates.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim rKey As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        rKey = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(rKey) Then
            If Len(rKey) > 0 Then
                dict(rKey) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No folder names found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy folders
    
    ' Append a trailing Path separator to the Destination Path!!!
    Dim dPath As String
    dPath = fso.BuildPath(DESTINATION_FOLDER_PATH, Application.PathSeparator)
    
    Dim sPath As String
    
    For Each rKey In dict.Keys
        sPath = fso.BuildPath(SOURCE_FOLDER_PATH, rKey)
        If fso.FolderExists(sPath) Then
            fso.CopyFolder sPath, dPath ' , True ' is default for 'overwrite'
        End If
    Next rKey
    
    MsgBox "Folders copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```